# only students who have the best mark

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple relation between student and marks :

Student :

```
+------------+-------------+
| idStudent  | NameStudent |
+------------+-------------+
|         1  | Student A   |
|         2  | Student B   |
|         3  | Student C   |
+------------+-------------+
```

Marks :

```
+----------+------+-----------+
| idMarks  | mark | idStudent |
+----------+------+-----------+
|        1 | A    |         1 |
|        2 | A    |         1 |
|        3 | A    |         1 |
|        4 | A    |         2 |
|        5 | A    |         2 |
|        6 | C    |         3 |
|        7 | A    |         3 |
+----------+------+-----------+
```

I only want to have students who have a "A" in every exam they passed

```
SELECT *, COUNT(mark)
FROM student S
INNER JOIN marks M ON S.idStudent = M.idStudent
WHERE M.mark = "A"
GROUP BY S.idStudent
```

I tried this but I reach deadlock when I try to compare the number of exam they passed and the number of A they have...

I also tried with subqueries but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT S.idStudent
FROM student S
INNER JOIN marks M ON S.idStudent = M.idStudent
GROUP BY S.idStudent
HAVING COUNT(mark)=SUM(mark='A');-- compare all marks with marks that are only 'A'
                                 -- if equal then every mark is 'A'
```

Answer (score 2):

- Group by on the student
- Find all distinct marks obtained by the student and put them in a comma separated string using [Group_concat](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/) function
- Just filter out (using [Having](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx) clause) the ones having only one overall distinct mark, that is **A**

Use the following query:

```
SELECT S.idStudent, 
       S.NameStudent, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT M.mark) AS unique_marks 
FROM student S
INNER JOIN marks M ON S.idStudent = M.idStudent
GROUP BY S.idStudent, S.NameStudent
HAVING unique_marks = 'A'
```

Comment: this approach seems a little more tricky but a lot interesting

Comment: @ZeyukanIch' well personally I feel it's a very handy approach in lot of scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the student IDs, you can `LEFT JOIN` students to marks, including a condition in the join clause for the mark not being A. Then, the `WHERE` clause would only include students with non-matching rows:

```
SELECT Student.idStudent 
FROM Student
    LEFT JOIN Marks BelowA ON
        BelowA.idStudent = Student.idStudent
        AND BelowA.mark <> 'A'
WHERE BelowA.idStudent IS NULL
```

Comment: @LukaszSzozda: I tested, and this is not the case. If a student only has As, then the query will return 1 row for that student, because of the `LEFT JOIN` and `WHERE` condition. With OP's example data, Student A (`idStudent=1`) has all `A`s, and only has one entry in my query.

Comment: Ok, what with case when Student hasn't got any Mark?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda---well, you could quibble semantics and say that such a student fulfills the requirements (for this student, there's no exam they **didn't** get an `A` on). You could also add another criterion to exclude these students (e.g. `EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Marks WHERE idStudent = Students.idStudent))`), or `INNER JOIN` on the entire `Marks` table (which would, as you point out, necesittate a `DISTINCT` clause).